# How to use Telerik.Web.Mvc an older version with asp.net MVC 5?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, telerik, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

Currently I am using Telerik.Web.Mvc.dll with asp.net MVC 2. I need to migrate my application to asp.net MVC 5. Is there any way I could achieve this ?
Thanks in advance.

```
<% Html.Telerik().Grid(Model.Data).TableHtmlAttributes(new {@class="table table-hover table-responsive table-striped cont_TableCustom freeze_Table "})
   .Name("Details")
   .DataKeys(datakeys =>
   {
       datakeys.Add(p => p.ID).RouteKey("ID");
   })
   .DataBinding(databinding => databinding
   .Server().Delete("Delete", "Home"))
   .Columns(columns =>
    {
       columns.Bound(p => p.Name).Title("Name");
       columns.Bound(p => p.No).Title(" No");
    }).Pageable(Pager => Pager.PageSize(PageSize).Enabled((Model.Data.Count() > PageSize) ? true : false)).Sortable().Render();
%>
```

I just need to use this grid with MVC 5.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as long as you pass the same model from the controller to the view, it should work.
All you have to do is change the syntax from <% %> to just @Html.Telerik().RestOfTheCode....
Have a look at the Razor syntax at: https://www.w3schools.com/asp/razor_syntax.asp

PS: Also declare the model type at the top of the page with
@model TypeOfYourModel